# pqdm.processes 'AttributeError' object is not iterable while it works with pdqm.threads

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tqdm, pqdm

I have a newbie python issue which I do not understand.

I have working code for parallel execution using pqdm. It works if I use `from pqdm.threads import pqdm` and fails with `'AttributeError' object is not iterable` if I switch to `from pqdm.processes import pqdm` instead.

What is it that I do not understand here? What can be the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: The obvious answer is that `pqdm.threads.pqdm` and `pqdm.processes.pqdm` are different.  One is iterable, the other is not.

Comment: If the first way works, then just use that.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks. The "issue" is that my CPU is not fully utilized when I use from pqdm.threads import pqdm . It looks idle and specific process runs almost 20 minutes (for no reason in my view). So I git the idea to perhaps switch to from pqdm.processes import pqdm and my CPU will be utilized.

Comment: It would help if you posted the full exact error message traceback.